# Which is preferable compress and encrypt or just encrypt and no compression in purely security perspective and not in resources or efficiency?

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, compression

I want to know what attack am I exposed to if I implement one of the two method. I'm pretty sure both of them are not 100% fool-proof and both of them are expose to traffic-analysis attack if I do sent the files through the internet. I want to know a specific threat or way that can allowed me to comprehend which one is better for my scenario which is the most secure one.

Right now, I just confuse because both of them expose to certain attack. And if I want to make a decision according to efficiency surely "with compression" would have won but my focus is mainly on security of the data.

The flaws of compression is that it can expose an information but to what extend. Does it make the security of my encryption become penetrable (if it is that easy to decrypt). That's all from me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It short: compression before encryption will impact security in some use cases but not in others. Compression before encryption will be a problem if the attacker can both define parts of the encrypted data and also observe the length of the encrypted data. The information provided by you are not sufficient to decide if your use case is affected or not. Thus, when in doubt don't compress.